# Joomla! - Database tables related with users

Tags: database, joomla, registration

I wanna make my own registration form as i need to include extra fields for the users. And it seems that there isn't any FREE extensions that is able to do it. So i have to find out how to insert the users into the database.

I have found out that there are 3 tables related with each other when creating a new user:
1. jos_users
2. jos_core_acl_aro
3. jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map

But i am running Joomla! 2.5.1 for my website and my database does not have jos_core_acl_aro and jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map tables!!

May i know what are the tables to take note of when i'm doing my own registration form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is actually two things:

1. Your own registration form
2. add fields to jos_users

If you're looking for a plugin for the registration form:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/13753

Steps to add fields for jos_users you can find here:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2654947

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an entry to `#__user_usergroup_map`, the 2nd field "group_id" must exist at `#__usergroups`.